# Repair or rebuild driver store

Tags: windows-8, drivers

I have a Windows 8.1 PC that I had to install Rutoken Drivers utility on. Apparently older version uninstall has done some damage to Windows driver store and now I receive a 1603 Windows Installer error whenever I try to install the package. I have narrowed the problem to installing/uninstalling drivers via `pnputil` returning error 13 (0x0D) with the description "Invalid data". What data is invalid is beyond my comprehension.

The trouble is that now I cannot install *any* driver, and either `pnputil` or its wrapper or underlying API call returns the same 0x0D error in my face. I have tried `sfc /scannow` with zero errors, `dism /online /cleanup-image /scanhealth` - 1 "payload corruption" and failure repairing that "corruption" with 0x80240021 (timeout downloading from Windows Update - the affected package does not exist in there).

Searching Google did not return any additional possible actions. I have even tried to manually remove all registry entries that include the info on these drivers along with all the files in both %SystemRoot%\inf and %SystemRoot%\system32\DriverStore\FileRepository, this resulted in drivers officially being uninstalled, thus I receive 2 less errors while installing that package, but the main problem persists. I am out of options barring Windows reinstall, but this is yet not allowed because of sensitive payload running on the server.

Is there any way to repair the metadata in Windows 8 driver store?

UPDATE: Relevant portion of `setupapi.dev.log` follows. This is the part with the first recorded error:

```
[Boot Session: 2014/04/30 10:21:02.496]
>>>  [Device Install (DiShowUpdateDevice) - USB\VID_04A9&PID_3155\D1FD7268198E4248B690D4C39EF7FA4D]
>>>  Section start 2014/05/20 13:12:15.744
      cmd: "C:\WINDOWS\system32\mmc.exe" "C:\WINDOWS\system32\compmgmt.msc" /s
     dvi: {DIF_UPDATEDRIVER_UI} 13:12:15.757
     dvi:      No class installer for 'Canon Digital Camera'
     dvi:      No CoInstallers found
     dvi:      Default installer: Enter 13:12:15.766
     dvi:      Default installer: Exit
     dvi: {DIF_UPDATEDRIVER_UI - exit(0xe000020e)} 13:12:15.771
     ndv: {Update Driver Software Wizard for USB\VID_04A9&PID_3155\D1FD7268198E4248B690D4C39EF7FA4D}
     ndv:      Driver package 'C:\WINDOWS\INF\wpdmtp.inf' exists under 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\wpdmtp.inf_amd64_5c9850dbde92cf4e\wpdmtp.inf'.
     dvi:      Searching for hardware ID(s):
     dvi:           usb\vid_04a9&pid_3155&rev_0001
     dvi:           usb\vid_04a9&pid_3155
     dvi:      Searching for compatible ID(s):
     dvi:           usb\class_06&subclass_01&prot_01
     dvi:           usb\class_06&subclass_01
     dvi:           usb\class_06
     dvi:      Class GUID of device changed to: {eec5ad98-8080-425f-922a-dabf3de3f69a}.
!!!  ndv:      Device install failed for device.
!!!  ndv:      Error 13: The data is invalid.
     ndv:      Installing NULL driver.
     ndv: {Update Driver Software Wizard exit(0000000d)}
<<<  Section end 2014/05/20 13:12:23.679
<<<  [Exit status: FAILURE(0x0000000d)]
```

This part is what happened at reinstallation of Rutoken Drivers:

```
>>>  [SetupCopyOEMInf - C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\rtusb.inf_amd64_19d5bedeabf631df\rtusb.inf]
>>>  Section start 2014/05/26 18:28:17.278
  cmd: C:\Windows\System32\MsiExec.exe -Embedding D9545376710EF829AA7DF44D8CF55F60 M Global\MSI0000
 inf: Driver Store Path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\rtusb.inf_amd64_19d5bedeabf631df\rtusb.inf
 inf: Published Inf Path: C:\WINDOWS\INF\oem8.inf
<<<  Section end 2014/05/26 18:28:17.278
<<<  [Exit status: SUCCESS]


>>>  [SetupUninstallOEMInf - oem8.inf]
>>>  Section start 2014/05/26 18:28:17.356
      cmd: C:\Windows\System32\MsiExec.exe -Embedding D9545376710EF829AA7DF44D8CF55F60 M Global\MSI0000
     inf: Driver Store Path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\rtusb.inf_amd64_19d5bedeabf631df\rtusb.inf
     sto: {Setup Delete Driver Package: C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\rtusb.inf_amd64_19d5bedeabf631df\rtusb.inf} 18:28:17.356
!!!  sto:      Failed to call to delete driver package. Error = 0x0000000D
     sto: {Setup Delete Driver Package - exit (0x0000000d)} 18:28:17.372
!!!  inf: Failed to delete package from Driver Store
!!!  inf: Error 13: The data is invalid.
!!!  inf: Error uninstalling OEM INF 'C:\WINDOWS\INF\oem8.inf'
!!!  inf: Error 13: The data is invalid.
<<<  Section end 2014/05/26 18:28:17.387
<<<  [Exit status: FAILURE(0x0000000d)]
```

Since then every install/uninstall fails with 0x0000000D.

Comment: The tool you would normally use for this is DISM there really isn't another tool.  Are you able to use a restoration point?

Comment: No, the server in question does not have a RP. I've tried DISM already to no effect, sadly.

Comment: You can supply DISM an external image from the one that is contained within your system just have to have an .ISO or a Windows 8 installation Disk

Comment: Hmm, indeed, trying right now.

Comment: Well, it did fix the detected 1 corruption, but the driver installation still fails with the same error.

Comment: Are you sure the driver supports 8.1?

Comment: Pretty positive, there are two more boxes that have this driver installed, and vendor declared WHQL compatibility level for Windows 8.1.

Comment: If the developer says VHQL compatibility then the answer to my question is **Yes**. Can you simply extract the driver from the installer manually and point the Windows to that driver?

Comment: Yes I did that, running `pnputil -a` resulted in the same 0x0D Invalid data error.

Comment: share the setup api logs from **C:\Windows\Inf**

Comment: @magicandre1981 Here you are. (Hmm, the culprit appeared to be the camera, but still.)

Comment: activate verbose logging (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff550808%28v=vs.85%29.aspx - LogLevel = 0x7070) and try to install again. Now post the new logs.

Comment: Log level was set to 4001, I've set it to 7070 but no changes in logs. It's just that, get inf, get cat, `!!!  sto: Failed to call to import driver package. Error = 0x0000000D`, failure(0x0D).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The apparent answer is no, you cannot fix the driver store. Ended up reinstalling Windows just for that.